# innerHTML not getting values Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, innerhtml

Purpose: My code should get the all the links that are available under a drop down menu. It should print all those links under that specific menu.

Site used for testing: http://test1.absofttrainings.com and the specific menu option is Test Pages.

Question/Problem: The code is not printing 2 values that I am expecting, there are 2 links under Test Pages.

Code:
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://test1.absofttrainings.com/#");

```
    //Step1: Create a List of WebElements to put all the links 
    //  the //a will give me all the links associated
     List<WebElement> drop_downs= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Test Pages')]//a"));



     for(int i=0;i<drop_downs.size(); i++){
         WebElement e= drop_downs.get(i);
         String text=e.getAttribute("innerHTML");
         System.out.println("Links are " + text);
     }
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code snippet**

```
//find all the links of sibling(s) of the 'Test Pages' 
List<WebElement> drop_downs= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Test Pages')]/following-sibling::*//a"));

for(WebElement links : drop_downs){
     System.out.println(links.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon because there is no explanation of why or how it works and solves the OP's question. Please take a minute to add some explanation of your code. Thanks.